# How are HTTPS Requests intercepted?

Tags: android, http, https

I have recently made an android app that sends some information to the server via a HTTPS Post request. The information is stored in the body of the request. However, one of the app users seems to be modifying the content of the request. I'm not sure how this is possible as I was under the impression that if HTTPS is used, the content is completely encrypted and is impossible to intercept. However, now it seems like that assumption is wrong.

Could someone please help me understand how it is possible that the user intercepted this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways this can be done, but the easiest, and it's a valuable development tool, is Charles Proxy.  The scenario you describe above is very simple :)

http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: But how would this proxy have access to the server's certificate and private key?

Comment: Check out Charles' website.  You setup a trusted certificate on the device so that Charles can proxy the requests.  Everything is completely decrypted and you can modify any part of the message: headers, body, etc.

Comment: haha, i remember when i use this to "hack" point in a game for facebook :P it very very simple to do that you describe!

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS/TLS protocol doesn't protect against man in the middle attacks. Unless you verify the server certificate AND make sure it is signed by a trusted CA AND this CA is not compromised, you are never certain whether you are talking to the server or to a some proxy. Oh, and SSL stack can be compromised too.